# trigger function in custom class on WooCommerce action

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, action

I am using the following class to have a directory created with dynamic value - based on a woo custom checkout field. Works perfect on page refresh and directory is created like expected.

just need this to only trigger/instantiate on the WooCommerce actions

```
woocommerce_order_status_completed
```

or

```
woocommerce_order_status_changed
```

or

```
woocommerce_thankyou_page
```

how can this be done so that it does not always run every time a page is loaded to decrease the load and have better efficiency in general.

**here is the complete class**

```
//add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'pos__URL', 'init' ));    //uncomment to trigger on page refresh
class pos__URL {

public static function init() {
    $POS__sys_URL = __CLASS__;
    new $POS__sys_URL;
}

public function __construct()
{
add_action('init', array($this, 'pos__URL_Field'));
}

public function pos__URL_Field()
{
    //--------to access the value----start-----
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));
    //add the id of the custom meta field that lies in the order
    $meta_data = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
      $meta_data[$order_id] = get_post_meta($order_id, '_engx_text_field_id', true);
    }
    //--------to access the value----end-----
    
    if( isset($meta_data[$order_id]) ) { //is the field set
    
        $curdir = getcwd(); //delcare variables
        
        if (!file_exists($meta_data[$order_id])) {

            if( mkdir( $curdir . "/" . $meta_data[$order_id], 0777) ) {
                    
                    //below section for for testing purposes to see if the command ran - and yes shows correctly and creates directory as expected IF the POS url is set - (triggers at the moment on page refresh)
                    echo "directory created";         //comment out when done testing
                }else{                              
                    echo "directory NOT created";     //comment out when done testing
                }
            }
    }else{
        
    if( empty($meta_data[$order_id]) ) {
        //do nothing
    }
  }
}
} //end function
```

I have tried the following to set the **action** on the **inside** of class but I am not doing it right and it didn't work

```
class pos__URL
{
public function init()
{
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', array('pos__URL') );
}

public function __construct()
{
add_action('init', array($this, 'pos__URL_Field'));
}

public function pos__URL_Field()
{
    //--------to access the value----start-----
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));
    //add the id of the custom meta field that lies in the order
    $meta_data = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
      $meta_data[$order_id] = get_post_meta($order_id, '_engx_text_field_id', true);
    }
    //--------to access the value----end-----
    
    if( isset($meta_data[$order_id]) ) { //is the field set
    
        $curdir = getcwd(); //delcare variables
        
        if (!file_exists($meta_data[$order_id])) {

            if( mkdir( $curdir . "/" . $meta_data[$order_id], 0777) ) {
                    
                    //below section for for testing purposes to see if the command ran - and yes shows correctly and creates directory as expected IF the POS url is set - triggers at momment on page refresh
                    echo "directory created";         //comment out when done testing
                }else{                              
                    echo "directory NOT created";     //comment out when done testing
                }
            }
    }else{
        
    if( empty($meta_data[$order_id]) ) {
        //do nothing
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the same pattern you use for the `plugins_loaded` but this time replace it with whatever action you want to trigger the callback for. eg:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array( 'pos__URL', 'init' ));`

`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', array( 'pos__URL', 'init' ));`

`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_page', array( 'pos__URL', 'init' ));`

The init function of the pos_URL class will trigger when any of the above actions occur.

Comment: was my first attempt with no luck.

Comment: Where did you calling the add_action? functions.php or from a plugin

Comment: being called from custom plugin, add_action was added to same file as the class, following same pattern